# Advice on solving zebra type puzzle

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I need your help in solving the following problem:

There're 3 girls (Ann,Susan,Alice) who need to choose what color shoes and dress to wear. There're 3 possible colors for shoes and dresses: white, blue and green.

Main conditions:

- Ann hates white.
- Susan wears shoes and dress of same color.
- Alice has white shoes.
- Alice and Ann's shoes and dress have different colors.

My code satisfies only 2 conditions; I'm kinda having hard times meeting conditions on the same color for Susan and whereas other girls need to have different color garments.

Here's what I come up with:

```
PREDICATES
   girl(symbol)
   shoes(symbol,symbol)
   skirt(symbol,symbol)
   hates(symbol,symbol)
   will_wear(symbol, symbol, symbol)


CLAUSES
   will_wear(X,Y,Z):-
      girl(X),
      shoes(X,Y),
      skirt(X,Z),
      not(hates(X,Y)),
      not(hates(X,Z)).

   girl(ann).
   girl(susan).
   girl(alice).

   hates(ann,white).

   skirt(_,white).
   skirt(_,blue).
   skirt(_,green).

   shoes(alice,white).
   shoes(_,blue).
   shoes(_,green).

GOAL
   will_wear(Name,Shoes,Dress).
```

Code above works fine, but gives too many solutions. Plus, I couldn't come up with any logical solution for the condition for Susan to wear shoes and dress of same color.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? It's ok if it is, just let us know and tell us what you've tried so far....

Comment: It actually is. The code above is the thing I came up with myself. Teacher gave us only conditions. I think main problem is the logic of solution. I've already been thinking on this for 2 hours. Kinda makes me wanna laugh at myself for that :)

Comment: Don't feel bad.  I spent way more than 2 hours on my first 'simple' prolog assignment.  Keep at it.  It's a different way of thinking.  I'd love to help you, but all that knowledge has left my brain years ago... :)

Comment: Could you indent your will_wear clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the conditions correctly, they're not what Shurane answered.

This will make sure that a girl wears a dress and shoes with the same colour:

```
same_color(Girl) :-
    shoes(Girl, Color),
    dress(Girl, Color).
```

I'll leave the different colour one as an exercise, but hint that to say two things are not the same you say `A \= B`. Please leave a comment if you have a hard time with different_color - and tell me what you've tried.

Comment: I found a solution for similar problem online. Like I said logic there is a bit different. Thank you all for your help. Will try to develop my version of solution though :)

Comment: idea is that for similar colors we use correspond clause

correspond(X,Y,Z):-girl(X),shoes(Y),dress(Z),
X=susan,Y=green,Y<>Z.

And that should be customized for each of the girls.

Then there's solution clause:
solution(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3):-
X1=susan,correspond(X1,Y1,Z1),

X2=alice, correspond(X2,Y2,Z2),

X3=ann, correspond(X3,Y3,Z3),
Y1<>Y2, Y2<>Y3, Y1<>Y3,
Z1<>Z2, Z2<>Z3, Z1<>Z3.

Comment: Isn't that the same as `only_wears` in my code? Also, `dress()` ought to be `skirt()`.

Comment: I think what configurator meant was that clause's logic has to be bind to "color" attribute

Comment: Ooh, I see. Although, that still seems a lot like `only_wears(Girl, _)`

Comment: @Shurane: Yes, it _does_ the same thing. But it doesn't _mean_ the same thing. The important thing in software development in general and Prolog in particular is that the meaning are all correct. Everything else follows from that.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
only_wears(Girl,Color):-
    shoes(Girl, Color),
    skirt(Girl, Color).

different_shoes(F, S):-
    shoes(F,F_color),
    shoes(S,S_color),
    not(equals(F_color,S_color)).

different_skirts(F, S):-
    skirt(F,F_color),
    skirt(S,S_color),
    not(equals(F_color,S_color)).
```

I do wonder if there's a way to pass clauses to other clauses, because `different_shoes` and `different_skirts` are identical in structure.

You would initialize it like so:

```
only_wears(ann, white).
different_shoes(alice, ann).
different_skirt(alice, ann).
```

Comment: `not(equals(A,B))` should really be `A \= B`, I think

Comment: And about passing clauses, it's possible but not pretty.

Comment: i had the same idea on clauses, but couldn't find answer anywhere. Your version still gives 19 solutions, but i need only 3.

Comment: Do you mean there should only be 3 solutions?

Comment: yep, other solutions are just duplicates or it's impossible (girls can't wear same shoes or dress)